# Show different inline query results when triggered in private chat with bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to reproduce @stickers bot behavior: when it offer to select a sticker (ex. for reordering it) it sends me a message with a button which redirects me to inline query. Obviously, this button have `switch_inline_query_current_chat` parameter. But inline results with stickers shows only in this chat. When i'm trying to call inline query to stickers from other chat, it returns empty result list, but returns sticker list in private chat even if i type bot username manually (instead of pressing button).

Api tests as well as api documentation didn't provided anything helpful.
Is this an undocumented internal apis or something, or this behavior can be reproduced on bots from arbitrary users?

Comment: Does inline query has any id-like parameter? If yes it can be unique per chat.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok yes, inline query does have unique id, but it changes every time query is changed, so it can't be used this way

Comment: I meant that they can pass some id to switch inline as “@bot Id_text_here”